# Getting connection timeout when using sendmail

Tags: linux, connection, timeout, sendmail

I’m using CentOS (basically):

```
$ uname -a
Linux sandbox.my-domain.com 3.4.76-65.111.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 14 21:06:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and trying to send email using sendmail,

```
sendmail -v dave.alvarado@mydomain.com < /tmp/test.mail
```

In which the /tmp/test.mail file contains

```
Subject: test mail
first line of my message
```

However my email is failing with this in my /var/log/maillog file:

```
Feb 24 21:46:13 sandbox sendmail[1215]: s1OL1K3n001559: to=<dave.alvarado@mydomain.com>, ctladdr=<dalvarado@sandbox.my-domain.com> (602/600), delay=00:44:53, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210347, relay=aspmx3.googlemail.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with aspmx3.googlemail.com.
```

I’m able to send to this address using a normal mail client, so I was wondering how I can troubleshoot this timeout error.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot with the -X flag, e.g. `sendmail -X /tmp/sendmail`

This will log all SMTP traffic to /tmp/sendmail. At first glance, it looks like you are trying to relay to a domain not hosted by Gmail, which would require authentication.